Tool for managing video clips
I’m desperately searching for some tool, similar to a document management system, which I can use to sort an abundance of video clips. Platform is Linux.
I don't want to build up a deep hierarchy of folders to get them sorted, because that's what I have tried already. It ends up in a mess because every clip can be sorted into different folders depending of my current point of view. And as I'm not a machine my point of view isn't stable and I won't find the files a while after having them sorted away.
What I expect from the tool: Builds a database of all video files it finds in dedicated folders. Presents the files preferably with a preview feature. Starting an external player for preview is sufficient. Allows sorting the files by adding tags or categories. Preferably freeware / OSS. No cloud based tools.
Bonus: supports moving the files between folders or drives while keeping the database up to date without loosing added metadata.
What I have done to find some tool is extensive googling. I found several photo managing programs like shotwell and the like, but they show previews only for few formats. I'm using shotwell to categorize my photos, but many video clips appear garbled. Typical software called media managers on the other hand focus on music with only few functionalities usable for videos. Most metadata records seem to be predestined for music then.
There are a lot of media servers providing similar functionality but I don't want to run an extra service which is designed to stream video data just for cleaning up my collection.

Did you try digiKam? Which formats that you need weren't supported in "several photo managing  programs"?
